# How can I send a new list view from a listview to another activity?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with 5 items. Each item has a listview with 5 items. I would like to have this in a single activity using adapter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Expandable lists let you create lists within lists.

They’re ideal for list items that have sub-categories. The user selects an item from a scrollable list and another list pops open. They can then make another selection from this list. Here is the example and tutorial about this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Expandable lists.
it will help whatever you want like in your main listview have 5 item and each item have number of more item it will child of that item.